# Ignited Datatables selecting all columns even when column names are specified

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't seem to get this working and it's driving me nuts.
I'm using CodeIgniter's Ignited Datatables library I found on [github](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables)

I have the below method for getting records from a table joined to another:

```
public function get_templates_ajax() {
        $this->datatables->select('tem.template_id, tem.name, tem.vat, COUNT(itm.template_id) AS total_items');
        $this->datatables->from('templates tem');
        $this->datatables->join('items itm', 'tem.template_id = itm.template_id', 'left');
        $this->datatables->where('tem.user_id', $this->session->user_id);
        $this->datatables->group_by('tem.template_id');
        $this->datatables->add_column('actions', '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit_record btn btn-info" data-id="$1" data-name="$2" data-vat="$3">Edit</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_record btn btn-danger" data-id="$1">Delete</a>', 'tem.template_id, tem.name, tem.vat');
        return $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Yes, I have a field named `user_id` in both tables, but I'm not selecting the column, however, I get this error: Duplicate column name 'user_id'.

I specified the columns I want selected as seen below:

```
$this->datatables->select('tem.template_id, tem.name, tem.vat, COUNT(itm.template_id) AS total_items');
```

I know if I wanted to select the user_id column, I'd use an alias, but I'm not selecting it.

Doing `$this->db->last_query();` dumped this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `templates` `tem` LEFT JOIN `items` `itm` ON `tem`.`template_id` = `itm`.`template_id` WHERE `tem`.`user_id` = '1' GROUP BY `tem`.`template_id`) SqueryAux
```

So it seems that the select method is being ignored while it is selecting all columns from both tables.
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You select * in the subquery of joined tables. Both with user_id, maybe you should specfic fields name instead of '*'


`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `templates` `tem` LEFT JOIN `items` `itm` ON `tem`.`template_id` = `itm`.`template_id` WHERE `tem`.`user_id` = '1' GROUP BY `tem`.`template_id`) SqueryAux
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging, I solved the problem by making some adjustments to the library.

Apparently, the problem was originating from the `get_total_results();` method in the class, more specifically these 2 line:

```
$subquery = $this->ci->db->get_compiled_select($this->table);
$countingsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (" . $subquery . ") SqueryAux";
```

The subquery variable was selecting all columns from the main table and joined tables using dear old `*`.

Here is what I did to fix the problem:

I replaced the `$subquery` line with this:

```
....
//ensure table with alias does not contain more than 1 space between original table name and alias
$this->table = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $this->table);
$tbl = explode(" ", $this->table);
//if table has alias, get it, else get table name
$table = count($tbl) > 1 ? $tbl[1] : $tbl[0];
$subquery = $this->ci->db->get_compiled_select($this->table);
//prefix table/alias to * so it selects columns from the main table only
$subquery = str_replace("*", "{$table}.*", $subquery);
....
```

Hope it helps someone.